# Identifying Stand-Alone Services on Android

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to make a distinction if a process is an app or a stand-alone service (i.e. - not a local service, but one which is running in its own process).

I am using ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses to get the running app process and am also using ActivityManager.getRunningServices to get the running services (unfortunately, the getRunningTasks API has been deprecated).

When I compare the results of both, I see that there are many of the same process names & IDs (pid) in both.

I have to assume with respect to the services whose process names also exist in the list derived from RunningAppProcesses , that those services are local services which reside within the app process (let me know if I am wrong in this assumption).

It seems the only way to know if a process is a stand-alone service would be to take both lists and then remove all the ones from the service process list whose PID matches one in the app list.  The result would give me the stand-alone services.

Is there an easier way to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get by with just `ActivityManager.getRunningServices`. Here is a method that should tell you if each `RunningServiceInfo` in the result has its own process. (To avoid getting the PackageManager every time, it is also passed in).

```
private boolean serviceHasDifferentProcess(PackageManager pm, RunningServiceInfo rsi) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    ComponentName cn = rsi.service;
    String pn = cn.getPackageName();
    PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(pn, 0);
    ApplicationInfo ai = pi.applicationInfo;

    String serviceProcessName = rsi.process;
    String appProcessName = ai.processName;

    return serviceProcessName.equals(appProcessName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Processes can host different Android components. In the manifest, you tell Android in which process to put each component. If you wanted to, you could have Android create a separate process for each and every Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, and ContentProvider. You could also have a process that hosts some services and some activities and another process that hosts other services and activities.

For this reason your question doesn't really have an answer.